# Yarn: queue with fair ordeing policy is unpreemptable in capacity scheduler

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Under my observsation, I found that if a Yarn cluster is using capacity scheduler, 2 queue in the cluster, A's odering policy is fifo, B's ordering policy is fair, then A can't not preempt resource from B even B's used capacity is over its' guarantee capacity.
But I can't find any source code or document to prove that, could you help me?

below is the simply config(2 queues A&B under root, with user admin):

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.ordering-policy=priority-utilization
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=A,B

yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.A.capacity=50
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.B.capacity=22

yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.A.maximum-capacity=80
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.B.maximum-capacity=60

yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.A.priority=50
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.B.priority=0

yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.A.ordering-policy=fifo
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.B.ordering-policy=fair

yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.A.user-limit-factor=2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.B.user-limit-factor=3

yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable=true
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.policies=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.monitor.capacity.ProportionalCapacityPreemptionPolicy
yarn.resourcemanager.monitor.capacity.preemption.monitoring_interval=15000
yarn.resourcemanager.monitor.capacity.preemption.natural_termination_factor=1
yarn.resourcemanager.monitor.capacity.preemption.total_preemption_per_round=0.1
```

what's more, the hdp version is 3.1.0.0-78

Comment: There are a lot of settings that you need to share for a good determination of what 'should' happen.  Can you provide your yarn config?

Comment: Sure. Thanks Matt. limited by the comment length，I post the config in the below answer，pls check

Comment: Just edit your question instead of adding an answer.

Comment: Did you hand code this?  You have a typo ordering-policy for 'A' is set twice.(And 'B' is not set)

Comment: Please also provide the pre-emption config for yarn: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.6/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#:~:text=%3E-,Capacity%20Scheduler%20container%20preemption,supporting%20preemption%20of%20application%20containers.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I already move the config to the question. And for the ordering policy setting, it's my hand code mistake. pls check the updated config, thanks

Comment: a quick look and this look reasonable.  let me dig into it after work.  I would suggest that you actually crank down yarn.resourcemanager.monitor.capacity.preemption.monitoring_interval to 1000 and demonstrate to yourself that this works.  With 15 seconds it's going to take it's sweet time to reclaim resources.  Either that or create some jobs that take hours to see it work out.